# Apache alias not working, WAMP

Tags: css, apache, wamp, alias, httpd.conf

I am using WAMP.

I edited the httpd.conf file to include:

```
Alias /static "c:/he/sites/browsbyboodah.com/htdocs/static"
```

When linking my .css's I use this path:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/reset.css" />
```

I cannot load the .css like this for some reason. What am I forgetting?

Thanks.

/* EDIT */

After a little debugging I found the following from a view page source and clicking on the css file:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/reset.css
css\reset.css could not be found
```

Answer (score 2):

check whether Apache `mod_alias` module is installed or not?  and remove `"`

```
Alias /static/ /sites/browsbyboodah.com/htdocs/static/
```

alternatively you can use **AliasMatch Directive**

> One subtle difference between Alias and AliasMatch is that Alias
>   automatically copies any additional part of the URI onto the end of
>   the file path on the right. AliasMatch does not.

```
  AliasMatch ^/static/(.*)$  /sites/browsbyboodah.com/htdocs/static/$1
```

Read this [`article`](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/apache-aliasing-and-redirection/) for more help

Comment: I have LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so in the httpd.conf. I made the suggested changes and still no dice. I'll read that article now. Thanks for the input.

Comment: I think your project location is wrong. wht site name is outside of htdocs?

Comment: What do you mean "site name" ? The files are here: C:\he\sites\browsbyboodah.com\htdocs\static\